# Why would anyone install openssh-client instead of openssh-server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, openssh

I installed openssh-server on two pc's. I can connect from both from the one to the other. So if `openssh-server` sends as well as receives ssh, why would you install the `openssh-client`, just to make sure nobody from another pc in the network can even try to log in to your pc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've answered your question yourself - why install `openssh-server` if you do not ever want to SSH into this machine - you would make your system less secure for no reason.

Comment: K, just making sure there was no other reason. Also, I think the ssh-client is installed by default, not the ssh-server.

Comment: This depends on the flavor of linux you are using. If you install certain distributions with minimal setup you'd might even end up without the ssh client

Comment: Sorry I meant for the ubuntu distribution.